# Core data complicated array

Tags: swift, core-data

I have this kind of array:

```
var vakken: [(String,[Int],[Int])]
```

but I don't know how i could put this in core data and pull it back?

Has anyone advice how to make this or even some code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes it is but i didn't got an answer on it so i would make a new question and try to explain it easier

Answer (score 1):

You could have a data model setup as follows (unordered arrays).

```
MainEntity
   (stringAttribute) String
   (quantityAttribute) <------------->> IntEntity
                                           (intAttribute) Int
   (quantity2Attribute) <------------>> IntEntity2
                                           (intAttribute) Int
```

If the two int arrays are reasonably similar, you could simplify

```
MainEntity
   (stringAttribute) String
   (quantityAttribute) <------------->> QuatityEntity
                                           (intAttribute) Int
                                           (type) Int
                                           (order) Int // optional
```

A less flexible hack would be to encode the array using `NSKeyedArchiver`, but this is very expensive.

Perhaps the easiest hack is to have a single entity with three `String` attributes, and you could transform the arrays into strings. Eg

```
let arrayToBeSaved = [1,2,3]
object.firstArray = arrayToBeSaved.map { "\($0)" }.joinWithSeparator(",")
// stores "1,2,3"

// retrieve
let storedArray = object.firstArray.characters.split{ $0 == "," }.map{ Int(String($0))! }
// retrieves [1,2,3]
```

This would even provide limited search capabilities, although not very efficiently.